# How to compile helloworld with Docker?

Tags: cleos, docker

I have this setup -

```
alias cleos='docker-compose exec keosd /opt/eosio/bin/cleos -u http://nodeosd:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8900'
```

I have this also started -

```
cleos set contract eosio.token build/contracts/eosio.token -p eosio.token
```

> Reading WAST/WASM from
>   build/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.wast...
>
> Error 3160009: No wast
>   file found Error Details: no wast file found
>   build/contracts/eosio.token/eosio.token.wast

I have also -

```
docker container ls
```

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
>   c452605e60b2        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/keos…"   11
>   hours ago        Up 11 hours
>                                          docker_keosd_1 0020b0b0ff69        eosio/eos           "/opt/eosio/bin/node…"   11 hours ago        Up 11
>   hours
>        0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9876->9876/tcp   docker_nodeosd_1

How can I get the wast files using docker?

Answer (score 2):

Before deploying your contract, you should first compile it using eosiocpp tool.
If you haven't aliased eosiocpp yet, try running,

```
alias eosiocpp='docker exec eosio /opt/eosio/bin/eosiocpp'
```

Then cd  to eosio.token folder, and there you can generate abi and wast file using the following commands,

```
eosiocpp -o eosio.token.wast eosio.token.cpp    #for wast file

eosiocpp -g eosio.token.abi eosio.token.hpp     #for abi file
```

Comment: I just got round to this after another issue. But I am using Docker. So eosiocpp is with the Docker framework (actually var/lib.....). There must be a command to setup the alias without knowing the exact path?

Comment: @TrevorOakley are u using eosio/eos-dev images?

Comment: I followed this - https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/Docker/README.md This uses docker build which uses Dockerfile but the docs also refer to docker-compose. Since then I have tried numerous more combinations and I keep getting all kinds of errors. The system partly works but I find something always fails.

Comment: Why don't u pull and use already built eosio images from repos? Btw, I've updated the answer for docker instance.

Comment: I heard that the standard repos did not have eosiocpp. There is a long article about this - https://medium.com/@ekkis/eos-development-on-docker-3f4eb9b680ec - I will try your idea.

Comment: That's not true. The eosio/eos-dev image contains everything you need. After running the container you can bashed into it and see it. The tools are available at /opt/eosio/bin/ folder. You better follow this: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart

Comment: It is true now. It makes things very difficult using the docker route. I grabbed the latest and struggled at this point too as 'eosiocpp' is not in the /opt/eosio/bin/ folder anymore